# Syntax error for Facebook Omniauth

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, omniauth, facebook-login

Thanks for taking the time to answer my question. So I've been integrating Facebook login with my application and I'm encountering a bug I can't seem to fix. The problem seems to be with line 22 :

```
user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
```

Here's the error I'm getting:

```
SyntaxError at /auth/facebook/callback
syntax error, unexpected tLABEL, expecting '='
SessionsController#facebook_login
app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb, line 22
```

sessions_controller.rb

```
def facebook_login
  if request.env['omniauth.auth']
    user = User.from_omniauth(env['omniauth.auth'])
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_back_or root_path
  end
end
```

user.rb

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  include Tokenable

  has_many :events

  has_secure_password, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.oauth_token.nil? }

  validates_presence_of :email, :first_name, :last_name
  validates_uniqueness_of :email, format: /\A[\w+\-.]+@[a-z\d\-.]+\.[a-z]+\z/i
  validates_length_of :password, minimum: 6, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.oauth_token.nil? }

  def to_param
    token
  end

  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_initialize.tap do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      user.save!
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

Update `self.from_omniauth` as below:

```
  def self.from_omniauth(auth)
    ## Use first_or_create
    where(auth.slice(:provider, :uid)).first_or_create do |user|
      user.provider = auth.provider
      user.uid = auth.uid
      user.first_name = auth.info.first_name
      user.last_name = auth.info.last_name
      user.email = auth.info.email
      user.oauth_token = auth.credentials.token
      user.oauth_expires_at = Time.at(auth.credentials.expires_at)
      ## Removed user.save!
    end
  end
```

Comment: That was a nice refactoring :) Thanks. Didn't fix the problem though.

Comment: Btw, I was just looking at this code again. Shouldn't it be find_or_create?

Comment: Read http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v3.2.13/active_record_querying.html#find-or-build-a-new-object  You can use either.

Answer (score 0):

I think I figured it out. The problem was

```
has_secure_password, unless: Proc.new { |a| !a.oauth_token.nil? }
```

I changed it to just has_secure_password and the world is good :)